# Remove my last print line in a while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, while-loop

Below is a function that I have wrote which works exactly the way I want. The user creates a list and then ultimately spits out a list that they created with no negative numbers. The problem I am having is removing my "Population not valid, please input a value higher then 0" after they execute my (-1 to quit). I want the user to be able to type -1 and then spit out the list with nothing else. So does anyone have any tips for my function below?

```
def getData():
    import math
    pop = []
    while True:
        user = raw_input("Please enter a population number (-1 to quit): ") 
        pop.append(user)
        if user <= '0':
            print "Population not valid, please input a value higher then 0"
        if user == '-1':
            break
    new_pop = map(int, pop)
    pop2 = filter(lambda x:x >=1, new_pop)
    print "Your population list is: ", pop2    
getData()
```

Answer (score 1):

just reverse the order of the 2 ifs

```
def getData():
    import math
    pop = []
    while True:
        user = raw_input("Please enter a population number (-1 to quit): ") 
        pop.append(user)
        if user == '-1':
            break
        if user <= '0':
            print "Population not valid, please input a value higher then 0"
    new_pop = map(int, pop)
    pop2 = filter(lambda x:x >=1, new_pop)
    print "Your population list is: ", pop2    
getData()
```

Comment: Thank you! Such an easy and simple thing to do.  A little bit new to all of this so I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: @Phil you are welcome we all have to start somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You could invert the order of your two `if` statements:

```
    if user == '-1':
        break
    elif user <= '0':
        print "Population not valid, please input a value higher then 0"
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is this if statement:

```
if user <= '0':
```

change to this

`if user <= '0' and user != '-1':`

This way, -1 is the only other input below 0 that will be ignored.

Or as stated above, reverse the order of the if statements.

Comment: Why did I get downvoted? I don't understand, my solution works correctly.